# Prove that if $a$ is a rational number and $a^2$ is an integer then $a$ is an integer.

Tags: rational-numbers

Question on a proof's review:

Proof by contradiction:

Suppose $a$ is not an integer. Then $a=p/q$ where $p$ and $q$ are coprime, $q$ is not 0, and $q$ is not 1.

Then $a^2 = p^2/q^2$.

This is as far as I've gotten, my t.a. says I'm on the right track, I just need help reasoning why my conclusion leads to a contradiction.

Please help.

Comment: Can you show that $a^2$ is a rational number?

Comment: @joebloggs "$a^2$ is an integer" is the assumption. >Integers are rational...

Comment: Here's a useful hint. The key point is $a^2$ is an integer by assumption. So where you have $a^2=p^2/q^2$, multiply across by $q^2$. Now you have $p^2=a^2q^2$, and all three of $p^2$, $q^2$ and $a^2$ are integers, so you can use what you know about divisibility in the integers

Comment: @Snulty correct. I meant to say, rational, non-integer. $a^2$ is an integer by assumption. So if you could lead to $a^2$ is a rational, non-integer, it would be a contradiction.

Comment: @joebloggs fair enough.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $\ \ (p/q)^2 \in\Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\, \color{}q\mid \color{#c00}p\cdot\color{#0a0}p\overset{\large (q,\color{#c00}p)=1}{\underset{\large \rm Euclid}\Rightarrow} q\mid\color{#0a0}p\,\Rightarrow\, \color{}p/q\in\Bbb Z\ \  $ **QED**

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Let $m$ be a prime number dividing $q$. Then $m|q^2|p^2$ thus $m|p$. Do you see the contradiction?

**Here is the complete proof:**

As $q \neq 1$ there exists a prime number $m$ dividing $q$.

Then, as $m|q$ we have  $m|q \cdot q=q^2$.

As $p^2=a^2q^2$ and $a^2$ is integer, we have $q^2|p^2$.

Therefore $m|q^2$ and $q^2|p^2$. This implies $m|p^2$.

Since $m$ is prime and $m|p \cdot p$ then $m|p$.

This proves that $m|p$. As $m|q$, this contradicts the fact that $p,q$ are relatively prime.

**P.S.** If you want a constructive proof, the same idea can be combined with the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic to prove that if $q^2|p^2$ then $q|p$.

Exactly as above you can first prove that all primes dividing $q$ must also divide $p$, and then you can prove that their power in $q$ is smaller than their power in $p$. I preferred the contradiction proof since it is much shorter.

Comment: Would the downvoter please explain?

Comment: I did not downvote, but here's a guess: there is no *explicit* justification of the crucial inference: $\, m\mid p^2\,\Rightarrow\, m\mid p.\ $ Such justification is *essential* for proofs at this level (or at least an explicit remark that it needs justification when hinting).

Comment: @BillDubuque Funny, I thought it was because I gave too many details, I tried to make it a hint instead of a complete answer... And that implication is just the definition of prime numbers .....

Comment: Question: If $gcd(p,q) = 1$ does this mean that the $gcd(p^2,q^2) = 1$ as well?

Comment: too many details? This answer is almost cryptic. your are skipping way too many steps. In particular, I don't think this is a helpful answer. I am downvoting.

Comment: @user122661 Yes, there a a few ways to see that, e.g. by uniqueness of prime factorizations, Euclid's Lemma,or  Bezout's Identity, or Gauss's Lemma, or the Distributive Law for gcds, etc. There are probably a few hundred posts here with proofs.

Comment: Alright, so I'll assume that in the proof, does that fact ($gcd(p^2,q^2) = 1$) lead us to our contradiction?  I assume it does, as the gcd of an integer would be the integer itself (unless the integer in question is 1, in which case the original conditions on $a$ contradict).

Comment: @MathcanbeFun No offense, but for a homework question I think one needs to leave the OP something to prove.. ANd here are the steps I am skipping:1) $m|q \Rightarrow m|q^2$... 2) $m|q^2$ and $q^2|p^2$ implies $m|p^2$ and finally 3) $m|p^2$ and $m$ prime implies $m|p$... Which of these three steps is not starightforward but cryptic?

Comment: OK, I guess I should erase this answer as it seems to be considered junk....

Comment: @N.S. For one example of why one may need more detail, see the erroneous proof just posted (which is quite common). But I think users should be more *constructive* before downvoting. We should try to work with the author to improve answers before downvoting them.

Comment: I will un downvote this answer, plus I will upvote if N.S. provides more details. thanks.

Comment: @MathcanbeFun Please don't upvote it, if you do I erase the extra details.

Comment: @MathcanbeFun For a homework question is a bad idea to include a complete proof, at least IMO... I tried to guide the student towards a solution instead of solving the problem for him/her... And I really think that the missing details were pretty straightforward...

Comment: I understand, but sometimes beginners have diffilcuties with proofs. maybe if you already know the material, then a hint is good enough and even healthy. I hope you understand me and sorry for downvoting at the beginning. cheers

Comment: @MathcanbeFun I don't mind the downvotes, but I would prefer if the downvoter explains his/her issues with the proof ;)

Comment: @N.S. I agree about giving away too much in a hint. It would have sufficed to write something like  $\,m\mid p^2\,\Rightarrow\,m\mid p\,$ because $\,p\,$ is $\,\ldots$ or something like that, and say something about how the proof depends *crucially* on the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic (uses both the *existence* and *uniqueness* of prime factorizations). It can fail in rings that lack these properties, i.e. rings not UFDs.

Comment: @BillDubuque Actually $m|p^2 \Rightarrow m|p$ depends only on the definition of prime numbers. The FTA appears in the proof in a very hidden way: it enters the proof when we speak about $p,q$ being relatively prime, UFD is needed to make sure the gcd is well defined... But I agree, the proof can be rewritten without the GCD, using the FTA directly ;)

Comment: @N.S. I suspect that FTA/UFD appears hidden because you overlooked a key invocation of it, viz. that atoms (irreducibles) are prime. This is equivalent to the *uniqueness* of factorizations into atoms (the nontrivial half of FTA/UFD, the *existence* of factorizations into atoms is trivial in $\,\Bbb Z).$